# How can I trace an ArgumentError in my test that fails in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I'm trying to find out why I'm getting an `ArgumentError` as shown below. How can I trace it when running my test to understand where it's coming from.  The line of code that it's referring to below is `assert @player.valid?`.

```
# Running:

E

Finished in 1.087226s, 0.9198 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
PlayerTest#test_player_attributes_must_not_be_empty:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
    test/models/player_test.rb:8:in `block in <class:PlayerTest>'

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: Do you get more backtrace if you run with BACKTRACE=1

Comment: `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
    test/models/player_test.rb:8`  so it is getting on ` test/models/player_test.rb` file line number 8 please post it

Comment: @FrederickCheung, oh thanks wasn't aware of that! It did send me some more information that seems to be pointing to validations and /lib/carrierwave/mount.rb ... though I don't have any validations on that model for any of my carrierwave attributes.  So I'm looking into it thanks!

Comment: @RajarshiDas I did post it, `assert @player.valid?`

Comment: I was able to fix it by updating my carrierwave gem doing a `bundle update` Thanks!